# Firestore Result into a Dictionary or Array (Swift)?

Tags: swift, dictionary, switch-statement, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Swift/App development and am trying to learn how to work with a Firestore database. I am getting a response from Firestore and I'm able to print out the results. I don't know how to manipulate or use the data that I am receiving. I suspect it's something to do with the data type, I think Firestore provides the data back as a dictionary.

I want to be able to take the results from Firestore and but it into a if/switch statement and check if the input is true or false.

```
    let db1 = Firestore.firestore()
    db1.collection("firstDatabase").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
```

How would I go about this after receiving the data? Would I assign to a variable first then manipulate it in an If/Switch statement to check if the values are true or false?

I know I'm missing some basics but thank you in advance for helping a new coder!

Comment: First don't force unwrap `querySnapshot!.documents`, use `querySnapshot?.documents`. What is the datatype of `document` ? You could use `Codable` to consume it. Refer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Answer (score 3):

Just create a dictionary with the data you are receiving from Firestore like this:

```
let dictionary = document.data() as [String : Any]
```

then check the dictionary values in you if or switch statements:

```
if dictionary["foo"] {
    //Do something here
}
```

if values for the dictionary are not bool:

```
if dictionary["foo"] == "bar" {
    //Do something here
}
```